# Switch line placements in bash

Tags: bash, text, sed, text-processing

is it possible to switch the placement of lines in bash given some string in the lines with sed?

For example:

I have the lines

```
2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084
3. partition1:
```

which are both output as part of a bash command to a text file.

Is there a way to reverse the order of these lines? To have them switch places to look like:

```
3. partition1: 
2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, pipe the output of whatever is producing the output to `tac` (that's `cat` in reverse) e.g. `some_command | tac`. If you need to write it in reverse to the file, then `some_command | tac > file.txt` Example: `printf "2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084\n3. partition1:\n" | tac`

Comment: If you have to use `sed`, then `some_command | sed -n '1!G;h;$p'`

Comment: In order to swap to arbitrary lines, have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331851/swapping-two-lines)

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the comments, yes, you can easily reverse the lines of output using either `tac` (`cat` in reverse order) or `sed`. In both cases you simply pipe the output of whatever command you are running to `tac` or `sed`. If you need to write the reversed contents to a file, then simply add a *redirection* to the end (e.g. `> file.txt`)

Using `tac` it is simply

```
some_command | tac > file.txt
```

Using `sed` it would be:

```
some_command | sed -n '1!G;h;$p' > file.txt
```

**Example**

Your output:

```
$ printf "2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084\n3. partition1:\n"
2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084
3. partition1:
```

Reversed output

```
$ printf "2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084\n3. partition1:\n" | tac
3. partition1:
2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084
```

or

```
$ printf "2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084\n3. partition1:\n" | sed -n '1!G;h;$p'
3. partition1:
2. diskusage1: 27.0572519084
```

Give them a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Looks like the 2nd and the 3rd are not only lines.

Comment: Yes, agreed, good point, but I can only go on what is in the question. If it is 1-50 then we would need a creative use of a counter and `read`  or `readarray` with `tac` or an exclusion range with `sed` or a combination of `head` and `tail` with either `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

That will do:

```
command | sed '2{h;d};3{p;x}' > file.txt
```